# Amend strings in key-value pairs Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I need to change all instances of a string within an array, I could do it like this, But is there not a more elegant solution when they are key value pairs?

```
var person = [];
person.push({
    name: 'John Smith',
    description: 'John Smith is tall.',
    details: 'John Smith has worked for us for 10 years.'
});
person.push({
    name: 'Michael Smith',
    description: 'Michael Smith is tall.',
    details: 'Michael Smith has worked for us for 10 years.'
});
person.push({
    name: 'Linda Smith',
    description: 'Linda Smith is tall.',
    details: 'Linda Smith has worked for us for 10 years.'
});

function replaceWordST() {
    var toReplace = "Smith";
    var replaceWith = "Jones";
    for (i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
        person[i].name = person[i].name.replace(new RegExp(toReplace, 'g'), replaceWith);
        person[i].description = person[i].description.replace(new RegExp(toReplace, 'g'), replaceWith);
        // etcetc
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to assume names will always be unique? Also, you can cache that _RegExp_.

Comment: Why you looking for another solution, you have working one, what the problem with it?

Comment: Yes the names will always be unique. What is wrong with this function is that if the data structure changes (key name added or amended) then the function will have to alter too. Is there not a way to specify all keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like an objet maybe:
http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/ekLmquap/

```
var replace = {
        replaceWordST:function(person) {
            var toReplace = /Smith/g;
            var replaceWith = "Jones";
            jsonData = person;
            for(var obj in jsonData){
                    if(jsonData.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
                    for(var prop in jsonData[obj]){
                        if(jsonData[obj].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                            jsonData[obj][prop] = replace.name(jsonData[obj][prop],toReplace,replaceWith);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return jsonData;
        },
        name:function(name,toReplace,replaceWith){
            return name.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> a more elegant solution

You can reduce the number of similar lines by using a nested loop

```
function replaceWordST() {
    var toReplace = "Smith",
        replaceWith = "Jones",
        re = new RegExp(toReplace, 'g'), // cache this!!
        keys = ['name', 'description', 'details' /*, etc*/],
        i, j; // don't forget to var these!!
    for (i = 0; i < theURLs.length; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < keys.length; ++j) {
            person[i][keys[j]] = person[i][keys[j]].replace(re, replaceWith);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better. I feel there must be a way to loop through all keys without having to define them...